# Find max $a$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{n^a} e^{-n} = 0 $

Tags: limits

Find maximum value of $a$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{n^a} e^{-n} = 0 $$

Clearly $a < 1$ also I checked that $a> 1/2$. But how do I narrow it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the natural logarithm of the expression says that the above limit is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}-n + n^a \ln n = -\infty
$$
You should check that this is true for all $a<1$, so there is no such maximal value.